# Interpolating specific data on Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, analytics, interpolation

I am trying to analyze an image sequence of a twisting ribbon (helicoidal structure) by measuring its pitch angle but I am facing some problems in the extraction of my results.

Basically what I am trying to do is building a code that calculate the pitch angle of the helix obtained experimentally : what I have done is : calculate the width of the ribbon at every value of the height and deduce the radius of the helix. The code itself works properly and it is shown below :

```
%% We go to the specific file that we want to treat

clear all
path = rdir('9V\largeur.mat');
load(path{1})

%% We define the spatial scaling
% We have a picture (echelle.tiff) that tells us 10cm=565pix

echelle=565/.1; %(pixel per meter). It's the frequency

% 
%     for z = 1:size(largeur,1)
%         
%     hauteur(z) = z/echelle; %Converting the height of the image to cm
%     
%     end

    hauteur=[1:size(largeur,1)]/echelle;
    
    for t = 1:size(largeur,2)
        
        signal_spatial=largeur(:,t)/echelle;
        signal_spatial=(signal_spatial-min(signal_spatial));
        radius = max(signal_spatial); % The radius corresponds to the maximum of the ribbon's width
    
        theta(:,t)=acos(signal_spatial/radius); % theta = acos(x/R)
    
    % figure(3)
   % title('Angle theta en fonction de la hauteur')
    
    % Plotting the angle theta as a function of the height z
    %
    
    %hold on
    
    %plot(hauteur,signal_spatial)
    %xlabel('hauteur (cm)')
    %ylabel(['theta(z,t=',num2str(t),')'])
    
    %title(num2str(t))
    
%     hold off
    end
        %cd('6V');
        %save('theta','theta');
        
        %cd ..
    
plot(hauteur,theta(:,401)) % we plot for the last image ranked 401
```

After that, I plot the values :

```
plot(hauteur,-theta(:,t),'r')
```

And I obtain this result :

[image]

And this is my problem : now I want to get rid of some branches in order to obtain the linear evolution of the angle as a function of the height: typically my goal is to "select" the first red branch and the second blue one in order to obtain a kind of "straight" line but I don't know how to do it ?

I have thought about trying to do it by working on the fact that the wanted branches correspond to the "increasing" part of the respective functions but how to do so ?

Could you suggest a way to do it please ?

Thank you !

PS : any suggestions please ?

Comment: If I understand what you want, you can slice your arrays for example like `hauture(hauture <= 0.019)` and `theta(hauture <= 0.019, t)`, assuming that the first linear part of your plot ends at about `h = 0.019`. Or are you asking for a way to automatically detect that value?

Comment: @MatteoV Thank you for your proposition : it is a very interesting idea but since I have several curves to analyze I would like to find a way to do it automatically as you have correctly guessed it : I think this is a little bit complicated but maybe you have a sophisticated way to do so ? Thank you again

Comment: There is a built-in function for that, [`ischange()`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischange.html). Alternatively, you could code a similar function for yourself: your intuition to look for the "increasing" part is right, and mathematically that equates to looking at the first derivative of your plot. Just pay attention to the noise and to the discreteness of your data.

Comment: Thank you a lot @MatteoV for your help : I will try this function and keep you informed about it, hope it will work... Thank you again